# Google Website optimizer with rails and jquery/ajax form (tracking an event)

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-website-optimizer

I have an ajax form that I'm trying to track with Google Web site Optimizer. The form sends an email.

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Enter your email address", :size => 40 %>
  <%= f.submit '', :class => 'subscriberSubmit', :id => 'subscriber_submit', :onclick => "doGoal(this);return false;" %>
<p>

<input id="subscriber_email" name="subscriber[email]" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="40" type="email">
```

My js.erb file:

```
$('.loadingImage').fadeOut();
$("#subscriber_submit").removeClass("subscriberSubmitInactive").addClass("subscriberSubmit");
$('#email_form').before("<div id=\"email_sign_up_failure\"><p>Uhm, something's wrong. Mind trying again?</p></div>");
```

The form works fine until I add the onclick call to set the GWO beacon, it's sending me to an undefined route. I'm assuming the conflict is with jQuery, and I figure I can maybe call the function from inside my js file instead of in an onclick event, but javascript is very new to me and I'm not sure how to call the function from within jQuery, which itself is in another piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['gwo._setAccount', 'UA-1195012']);
  function doGoal(that) { 
    try {
  _gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/136300081/goal']);
  setTimeout('document.location = "' + that.href + '"', 100) 
    } 
    catch(err){} 
   }
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- End of Google Website Optimizer Tracking Script -->
```

I tried jQuery's click event on the button id, but it didn't seem to work.

### EDIT

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscribers" class="new_subscriber" data-remote="true" id="new_subscriber" method="post">
<script> 
 $(function() {
    $( "#subscriber_submit" ).click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("subscriberSubmit").addClass("subscriberSubmitInactive");
        $('.loadingImage').fadeIn();
    });
});
</script> 

<p id="email_form"> 

<label for="subscriber_email">Email</label><br /> 
<input id="subscriber_email" name="subscriber[email]" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="40" type="email" /> 
  <input class="subscriberSubmit" id="subscriber_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="" /> 
<p> 

</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML (not your RUBY code) and your button click code.

Comment: It's posted, but it's just a pretty standard form -- and a pure HTML solution isn't necessarily going to help.

Comment: The point is not an "html solution" the point is more people know HTML than RUBY, so if you post the OUTPUT (HTML) rather than the source code you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: The point is the problem is likely in the ruby or rails specific code, so if you don't know ruby I'm not sure posting the form will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting the `_gaq.push(['gwo._trackPageview', '/136300081/goal']);` in my jQuery call after the `click` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to not use a submit button, but to use a regular button. What may be happening is the form gets submitted before your JS has finished executing. What you can do is submit the form in code at the end of your JS click event.